# Add a command which allows to color some words

Tags: color, renewcommand

I would like to define a command `\defi` which allows to color words with one color (not necessarily the color of the picture below) : to color the word `matrice`, I just want to type `\defi{matrice}`.

[image]

Here is a starting code.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb,graphicx,amsthm}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{pifont} %bouni
\usepackage{fancybox} %pour faire l'encadrement
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} %pour inserer une page pdf
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % pagestyle
%---- Dimensions des marges ---
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm}
%\usepackage{setspace}
%\onehalfspacing
%----
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}{Théorème}[section]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
\begin{itemize}
  \item [(i)] Une matrice $A$ est un tableau rectangulaire
d'élèments de $\mathbb{R}$.
  \item [(ii)] Elle est dite de taille $n \times p$ si le tableau
possède $n$ lignes et $p$ colonnes.
  \item [(iii)] Les nombres du tableau sont appelès les coefficients de $A$.
  \item [(vi)] Le coefficient situé à la $i$-éme ligne et à la $j$-éme colonne
  est noté $a_{i,j}$.
\end{itemize}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should look up what this means `\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}[section]` especially the `[section]` part. As for the other something like `\newcommand\HL[1]{\emph{\textcolor{orange}{#1}}}` (requires `xcolor`)

Comment: Related, as far as coloring: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580936/automatic-text-highlighting-based-on-a-dictionary, unless of course you prefer `\textcolor{orange}{\itshape matrice}` for every instance.  Also your question is really asking two completely unrelated questions (coloring, numbering).  Best if you keep a question limited to a single issue.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks for your comment. I don't understand how my question is closely related to the linked one?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have edited my question as adviced

Comment: In my cited answer, `\setsepchar{apple||banana}` is used to define the words you want "always colored".  While the syntax is slightly different than you seek (and I could make them the same syntax), the similarity of defining words you always want colored is what the two questions have in common.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I hope that you can help me by an answer. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do as @daleif is suggesting. The default color is orange; another color can be selected as e.g. `\defi[blue]{Bleu}` for a text in blue. I also added `\theoremstyle{definition}` before defining the `definition` theorem-style.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{amsfonts,amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Définition}

\newcommand{\defi}[2][orange]{\emph{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{definition}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item [(i)] Une \defi{matrice} $A$ est un tableau rectangulaire
    d'éléments de $\mathbb{R}$.
  \item [(ii)] Elle est dite de \defi{taille} $n \times p$ si le
    tableau possède $n$ lignes et $p$ colonnes.
  \item [(iii)] Les nombres du tableau sont appelés les
    \defi{coefficients} de $A$.
  \item [(vi)] Le coefficient situé à la $i$-ème ligne et à la $j$-ème
    colonne est noté $a_{i,j}$.
  \end{itemize}
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I replace ``\newcommand{\defi}[2][orange]{\emph{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}`` by 
``\newcommand{\defi[blue]{Bleu}}`` it does not work. Could you please help me if I want to change the color? Thanks a lot

Comment: @Schüler write instead `\newcommand{\defi}[2][blue]{\emph{\textcolor{#1}{#2}}}` to get blue as the default color
`